# Disable Developer Mode in Selenium Chrome Webdriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to disable developer mode in selenium using selenium-chromedriver so I don't have to log in everything I run the program. Currently this is the code I'm using.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/w/Desktop/chromedriver')
    Options = Options()
    Options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

How ever, when chrome pops up it's still in developer mode and is notifying me that "Chrome is being controlled by an automated test software".

Thanks!